# Insert $currentDate in java.util.List using Spring-data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I need to make an update and use the mongo operator **$currentDate** in a document I am using **spring-data-mongodb** the problem is, I can't traverse the element
Example:

```
Update update = new Update();
update.set("list", listOfObjects);
update.currentDate("list.someDate");
```

Error:

```
 Write failed with error code 16837 and error message 'cannot use the part (list of list.someDate) to traverse the element(...)
```

Someone know a solution or some workaround?
*Obs*. The date must be the MongoDb date, I can't use the Java date, I can't use this:

```
update.set("lista.dataAlteracao", DateTime.now())
```

Comment: Your error is not related to date. its more of your query/code is not able to identify how to access someDate which you are saying is sitting inside list. read a bit about positional operator and in such cases it is a savior.

you probably need to change your code a bit to include something like list.$.someDate. can you post how your document looks like so that i can give you a better answer.

Comment: list.$.someDate worked! Please, add this on the answer so I can choose you as the best answer

Comment: thanks. happy to help :) posted as answer. please accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is not related to date.

its more of your query/code is not able to identify how to access **someDate** which you are saying is sitting inside **list**. 
read a bit about **positional operator** and in such cases it is a savior.

> you probably need to change your code a bit to include something like 
>   `list.$.someDate`.

can you post how your document looks like so that i can give you a better answer.